# Point a subdomain from Route53 to CloudFront without using CNAME

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a subdomain (dev.example.com) and I need to point it to my cloudfront distribution (xyz.cloudfront.net). I did the following steps

1) Created the cloudfront distribution. DID NOT specify anything in the Cname field while creating the cloud front distribution.

2) Created an Alias record in Route53 with 'A' record and pointed dev.example.com to xyz.cloudfront.net.

But this setup does not work. It works only if I specify cname field in the cloudfront distribution.

Any ideas to get this working ?

Comment: In DNS terms, an `A` record means the domain or subdomain points to an IPv4 address, while a `CNAME` points to another domain or subdomain. An `Alias` record is something "created" by AWS to allow you to make your zone apex (the top domain, `example.com`) point to another domain or subdomain - In other words, it's equivalent to a `CNAME`, but specific to the apex. It was created because the DNS specification/standard doesn't support `CNAME`s for the apex - See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html for more info about Alias.

Comment: @jweyrich. He is using an ALIAS record. To create an ALIAS record you start with Type A and then enable ALIAS. He is speaking of the Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) in the CloudFront setup.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I have 2 cloudfront distributions created to support blue green deployments. I wanted a way to switch between both the distributions at the route53 level. If I have update the CNAME in cloudfront, the update is going to take a lot of time, each time I have switch between my blue and green cloudfront distribution. Any ideas on how to address this ?

Comment: Yes, enter both names in the CNAME field. CloudFront does not care if the origin matches the CNAME except for S3. Also create an SSL certificate via ACM with all your domain names and enable SSL.

Comment: @John Hanley: It doesn't make sense to create an `Alias` nor a `A` record for a subdomain that's going to point to another domain or subdomain.

Comment: Actually it does. ALIAS records are faster inside AWS than just A records. Also ALIAS records do not have a TTL which can make changes propagate faster. Plus queries to ALIAS records that point to CloudFront, ELB or S3 web sites (and more) are free.

Comment: @John Hanley, i tried that. But I cannot assign the same cname to both the cloudfront distribution. It gives me an error saying the cname is already attached to a different distribution

Comment: @AWSEnthusiastic that's expected as already explained in comments below - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185740/point-a-subdomain-from-route53-to-cloudfront-without-using-cname#comment81321386_47186059

Comment: @John Hanley, will try to switch the origin instead as suggested by Matt. Not sure if that is fast.

Comment: @jweyrich. For internal AWS services, you use an ALIAS A record as Route 53 is internally tracking the IP addresses of the target as it dynamically changes. If the target is outside of AWS or does not support ALIAS then you would use a CNAME.

Comment: @JohnHanley: Please, could you refer me/us to an official documentation that explains the behaviour you just described?

Comment: @AWSEnthusiastic. Swapping origins takes time also. Since B/G deployment is so common I am surprised, now that I think about it, that there is not a cool solution for this.

Comment: @jweyrich. Yes. I will follow up later with reference links.

Comment: @jweyrich. I have created a new question on this topic for my answers and links.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186999/route-53-configuration-which-is-better-alias-a-or-alias-cname-rrs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you only plan to use the CloudFront domain names, you must include one or more custom domain names, such as dev.example.com, in the Alternate Domain Names box if you want CloudFront to serve those domains.

Comment: This worked for me.  I had mistakenly created a CloudFront distribution without an alternate name.  A symptom of this it that when I went to create an alias to my subdomain to this distribution in Route 53, the distribution did not show up as an option until after I created the alias.

Answer (score 4):

CloudFront needs the so-called CNAME entry (Alternate Domain Name) in its configuration order to associate the incoming request with the distribution, and for this reason, they must be globally unique.

There is, however, an exception for wildcards that appear to conflict with single subdomains... they don't.

If you are using a subdomain, it should be possible to work around the CloudFront limitation on Alternate Domain Name assignments by provisioning the two distributions like this:

```
blue:  dev.example.com
green: *.example.com
```

Point the DNS record for dev.example.com to the CloudFront endpoint for **green**.  (And don't get ahead of me...)

You will find that in spite of the DNS setup, the **blue** side will handle dev.example.com requests because CloudFront does not actually know or care how the request was routed to it -- it uses SNI and the `Host` header to select the correct distribution.  Requests for `dev.example.com` will match blue regardless of which DNS record is used for the intermediate routing.

To switch traffic to green, remove the Alternate Domain Name from blue, and the wildcard on green will automatically start carrying the traffic.  No DNS change needed.

This is documented behavior:

> You cannot add an alternate domain name to a CloudFront distribution if the alternate domain name already exists in another CloudFront distribution, even if your AWS account owns the other distribution.
>
> However, **you can add a wildcard alternate domain name, such as *.example.com, that includes (that overlaps with) a non-wildcard alternate domain name, such as www.example.com**. Overlapping domain names can be in the same distribution or in separate distributions as long as both distributions were created by using the same AWS account. *(emphasis added)*
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-restrictions

Comment: The downvoter should comment.  This workaround is documented and performs as described.

Comment: @All. I think that Michael's answer is the best one and includes additional tips to help with the original question.

Comment: @Michael: As per your suggestion when I want to switch traffic to green, i can remove alternate domain name from blue. I understand this, but as per my understanding since this change is on the cloudfront, it will take atleast 15-20 mins to be  deployed. How is it different from having a single cloudfront and changing the origin whenever i want to switch. I do not see any benefit with this approach or am I missing anything ?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Can you try to answer my question above ?

Answer (score 3):

When accessing a CloudFront distribution, from anything other than the `*.cloudfront.net` URL, you must specify the CNAME. Even if you're using an `A` record.

You are creating an `ALIAS` record in Route 53. Even though you are not creating a `CNAME` record, you must specify your DNS entry `dev.example.com` in the `CNAME` field of your distribution.

Otherwise, CloudFront will not know what distribution you are requesting.

The alternative is to use a dedicated IP address, but that will cost you $600.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Actually I have 2 cloudfront distributions created to support blue green deployments. I wanted a way to switch between both the distributions at the route53 level. If I have update the CNAME in cloudfront, the update is going to take a lot of time, each time I have switch between my blue and green cloudfront distribution. Any ideas on how to address this ?

Comment: This is a known concern with CloudFront distributions. There is no way for multiple distributions to share a CNAME. So you'll need to figure a way in your blue green deployments to use different CNAMEs, or live with the delay.

Comment: Or, in your blue green, don't swap the distribution. Instead, just swap the origins.

Comment: Ok. Will give that a try

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with,

> Dedicated IP Custom SSL feature

It  will cost you $600 for dedicated IP Address at Cloudfront POP's.

More details [here](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/)

Once you have the dedicated IP, then you can create A record in DNS pointing to those IP Address(s).

Cloudfront works based on SNI (Server Name Indication) which needs a CNAME to map your distribution to.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't see any mention of SSL in the question. No need for SSL if OP doesn't care about it. If he does, there's still no need for the feature you mentioned - a free cert is enough.

Comment: There's no reason to believe that having dedicated addresses removes the reliance on the `Host` header in routing the request to the correct distribution.

Comment: Working without SNI is of course the entire point of the dedicated IP configuration, but that's not the same as working without a `Host` header mapping to a distribution via the Alternate Domain Name setting.

Comment: With dedicated IP Address, you don't need host header mapping to deliver to the right distribution.