# Route 53 Configuration - Which is better ALIAS A or ALIAS CNAME RRS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

Question:

When configuring Route 53 with AWS services such as CloudFront or ELB, which is better to use: an ALIAS A record or an ALIAS CNAME record?

Background:

An interesting thread developed on this question regarding the benefits of ALIAS records.

[Thread Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185740/point-a-subdomain-from-route53-to-cloudfront-without-using-cname?noredirect=1#comment81322501_47185740)

My intention is to create this question so that informed answers and knowledge can be collected in one place.

Comment: If `d1.example.com` were a `CNAME` to `d2.example.com`, would resolving `d1.example.com` possibly result in an old (cached) `d2.example.com` result? Or is DNS caching ignored while resolving a `CNAME` target? If so, then if `d1.example.com` were an `ALIAS` of `d2.example.com`, the problem would not occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "better," there's only one correct answer: the Alias RR type must be the same as the target RR.  For CloudFront, S3, ELB, etc., an Alias of type CNAME is not sensible, since the target is not a CNAME, it's an A.

But if the question is a choice between A alias=yes and CNAME alias=no, then A alias=yes is still the better solution.

The assertion at the other question is that Alias records are equivalent to CNAMEs but intended for the zone apex only is incorrect on both counts.

Alias A records cause ultimate behavior similar to CNAME behavior but they are preferred because they cut the DNS resolution time approximately in half by requiring only one resolver action, instead of two, and because they reduce your per-query cost to 0 when the alias target is an AWS service.

Comment: My understanding is that if you marked the record to be an "Alias" (non-standard thing created by AWS), it doesn't matter if it's A or CNAME, because AWS will ignore the entry value - You fill the `Alias Target` instead. The "Alias" thing created by AWS is their way of saying something like "Since you indicated you're pointing it to another AWS service, let us improve the DNS lookups to this record for you".

Comment: @jweyrich an Alias is an entry in a hosted zone that creates an **internal** (to Route 53) pointer to another entry in either the same hosted zone or one of the special zones correlated to AWS Services (e.g CloudFront).  An Alias record has a type, just like any RR does, and is only followed for requests of that type; it links to the alias target record by name and type. `dxxxexample.cloudfront.net` is an A record.  Its value is dynamic, not static, in order to route you to your nearest edge, and multiple IPs are returned, but it is definitely an A record, so you point to it with an `A` Alias.

Comment: ...in fact, if you want IPv6 resolution for your CloudFront distribution with a custom domain name, you need a *second* Alias record of type `AAAA`, since the `A` record alias only returns the `A` record (IPv4).  *["If IPv6 is enabled for the distribution and you're creating a second resource record set, choose `AAAA – IPv6 address`"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html)*

Answer (score 1):

Both will work, But you are going to want to use ALIAS. ALIAS is better due to the cost.

> *Queries to Alias records that are mapped to Elastic Load Balancers, Amazon CloudFront distributions, AWS Elastic Beanstalk environments,
>   and Amazon S3 website buckets are free.*

CNAME lookups have a cost associated with them.($0.400 per million queries).

ALIAS also have automation behind them, Any changes to ELB done by AWS will propagate them to your DNS.